# Comparing and thenComparingInt not working within the same string

Tags: string, sorting, java-8, java-stream, file-read

I'm trying to get some .txt files , reading them in order and then writing their content( with some logic) into an excel sheet.
The files are named like this:

```
FileB_60.txt
FileB_90.txt
FileB_120.txt

fileA_60.txt
fileA_90.txt
fileA_120.txt
```

In the end, I want them to be read just like that, ordered by name and number. If I don't use any sorting step, they're read randomly.

```
String fileExtension = ".txt";
    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(resourcesPath))) {
                Comparator<Path> byName = Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getFileName().toString());
                Comparator<Path> byNameAndNumber = byName.thenComparingInt(p -> Integer.parseInt(p.getFileName().toString().split("_")[1].replace(fileExtension, "")));
                for (Path eachFilePath : paths
                        .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(fileExtension))
                        .sorted(byNameAndNumber)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    ...
```

This way, they're read like:

```
FileB_120.txt
FileB_60.txt
FileB_90.txt

fileA_120.txt
fileA_60.txt
fileA_90.txt
```

So it seems like it's ordering only by the name (capital letter first)
I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong here, since I'm sorting within the same string

Comment: One important thing about `thenComparing...` methods: the comparator injected is only used when the initial comparator (called `byName` in your example) considers the 2 elements are equal, which is never the case in your example. To put it simply, the comparator injected is never called. So the comparator `byName` should work on the first part of the file name (the one before the `_`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing about [`thenComparing...`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.Comparator)) methods: the comparator injected is only used when the initial comparator (called `byName` in your example) considers the 2 elements are equal, which is never the case in your example.

The comparator `byName` must compare only the first part of the file name (the one before the `_`).

```java
Comparator<Path> byName = Comparator.comparing(
    p -> p.getFileName().toString().split("_")[0]);
```

Comment: Pretty straightforward. I didn't think of comparing just the first part,as I thought comparing whole string was enough to compare by name. But as you said, thenComparing is only triggered when the first comparator considers 2 equal elements. I've learned something :) ty!

Comment: I’d avoid potentially doing the work of `.toString().split("_")`  twice for every compared element. E.g. `Comparator<Path> c = Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getFileName().toString().split("_"), Comparator.comparing((String[] a) -> a[0]) .thenComparingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1].replace(fileExtension, ""))));`